# Polymorphic function as event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass this function as a callback to DOM event

```
var fooo = function() {
  $(this).append("foo");
  fooo = function() {
     $(this).append("bar");
  };
};

$("#hover").hover(fooo);​
```

This example should append "foo" and then "bar"s, however it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tNBx9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the function assigned to `fooo`, *not* the function that is assigned as the callback for the `.hover`.

For clarity, when you pass a function as a handler for an event -- like in the case of `$().hover(fooo)` -- you are not passing the variable of `fooo` but the funciton that it points to. If you reassign `fooo` to something else the original function is still the one bound as the event handler.

If I wanted to do what you are trying to do, then I would use a slightly different paradigm. Something like

```
var fooo = (function() {
    var altBehavior = false;
    return function() {
        $(this).append(altBehavior ? "bar" : "foo");
        altBehavior = true;
    }
})();

$("#hover").hover(fooo);​
```

The actual bound function never changes, but the context it *exists in* does.

Comment: Thanks for you solution, self-evaluated function works - you point me  [to this](http://jsfiddle.net/tNBx9/2/), which is a bit more suitable for my case. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This won't work either:

```
var fooo = function() {
    $(this).append("foo");
};

$("#hover").hover(fooo);

fooo = function() {
    $(this).append("bar");
};
```

Becuase you changed the variable but not the callback passed to the `hover` event.

You need to assign the new function as a callback:

```
var fooo = function() {
    $(this).append("foo");
};

$("#hover").hover(fooo);

fooo = function() {
    $(this).append("bar");
};
$("#hover").unbind('hover').hover(fooo);​
```

Comment: You need to remove the old event handler, otherwise you end up appending `foobar` instead of just `bar`.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the function `fooo` to the hover event and then changing the variable, without changing the handler itself.  You should unbind and then bind another function.  `hover` is shorthand for two events, so unbind each of them:

```
var fooo1 = function() {
  $(this).append("foo").unbind("mouseenter", fooo1).unbind("mouseleave", fooo1).hover(fooo2);
};

var fooo2 = function() {
  $(this).append("bar");
}

$("#hover").hover(fooo1);​
```